# No visible @ interface for 'NSMutableArray' declares selector 'appendData:'

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, nsdata

I am using the EGOTableViewPullRefresh library in my iOS app.  In order to implement it, I had to change my original class from a subclass of UIViewController to UITableViewController.  This apparently broke the way I store my data, e.g. in an NSMutableArray.

header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "EGORefreshTableHeaderView.h"

@interface PullViewController : UITableViewController  <EGORefreshTableHeaderDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{

    NSArray *news;
    NSMutableArray *data;

    EGORefreshTableHeaderView *_refreshHeaderView;

    //  Reloading var should really be your tableviews datasource
    //  Putting it here for demo purposes
    BOOL _reloading;
}

- (void)reloadTableViewDataSource;
- (void)doneLoadingTableViewData;

@end
```

implementation:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
    data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)theData{
    [data appendData:theData];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    news = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [DejalBezelActivityView removeViewAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Your `NSMutableArray *data` should be `NSMutableData *data`

Comment: change the data iVar or the data used in `connection:didreceiveResponce:` method this will solve your problem as local variable and global variables conflicts each other that is the problem :)

Comment: Contrary to what you told the compiler in your `@interface`, you aren't storing your data in an NSMutableArray.

Comment: @Wolvorin: What would the questioner want to change in `connection:didReceiveResponse:`, and why?

Comment: I answered the question first...still no response for me...

Comment: Rob had it right.  Sorry for not posting a specific question.  I wanted to know what was different about using UITableViewController vs. UIViewController that would break my usage of NSMutableArray, and how to fix it.

Comment: @user1349972: The problem had nothing to do with your class being a subclass of UITableViewController vs. UIViewController. You would have had the same problem either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSMutableData *)theData{
    [data appendData:theData];
}
```

from

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)theData{
    [data appendData:theData];
}
```

Also,

```
NSArray *news;
NSMutableArray *data;
```

Are you sure data is of kind Array? or it should be NSMutableData..check it once :)

Comment: Almost certainly `NSMutableData *data` since `appendData` isn't defined on `NSMutableArray`

Comment: Also he did alloc+init with NSData :)

Comment: Yes, I see that now.  Odd.

Comment: But he is not either accepting or commenting...this drive me sad and worry :(

Comment: Thank you, Anoop.  It was much simpler than I thought, and you had it right at the end when you said to change NSMutableArray to NSMutableData.  Many thanks!  Also, sorry for the late response.  I posted this question right before bed.

Comment: +1 up vote.  Just gained the up vote privilege as of this post!

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how you could have ever used a `NSMutableArray` instead of `NSMutableData`. In fact you are just instantiating a `NSMutableData`. So change your declaration of data to be of type `NSMutableData` in your class ivars.

Comment: I followed this great video tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJZcD3hfs3k  Changing the header to NSMutableData cleared all errors and warnings.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You declared `data` as `NSMutableArray`, and that class doesn't have any `appendData:` selector.

Comment: Yep you're right.  I had to change to NSMutableArray to NSMutableData.  What was strange is that it did work before when the class was UIViewController, then it didn't when it was UITableViewController.  If someone could explain why I would be interested to know :)

Comment: I guess you didn't use `[data appendData:theData];` in the previous code.